# Powershell script for deleting files starting with X and finish with_old Sharepoint online library

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, document-library, file, sharepoint-server

I need a script to delete files from the doc library in Sharepoint online. All files starting with specific latter (for example "X") should be deleted. And the ones starting with the same latter but ending on _old should be remain. And this is per month. All files but One X_old should be deleted.

Please for more explanation ask me, Thanks